Finding keywords in lists inside a dictionary
I have a dictionary that will have multiple dictionary / lists inside of it and I want to know how to go through each and search for keywords and add them total.
Example
dict1 = { "subDict1": "list1": [ "yes", "yes", "no" ] } }
Assume I had 10 sublists inside this dictionary.
How can I go through each list to count the total yes that I have?
I assume I need to do something similar to this
yes = 0
for d in dict1:
    for yes in dict1["subDict1"]
        yes +=1
print(yes)

Whenever I print it is always 0, and always runs like 108 times.
but thats about where I am stuck trying to figure out the rest.
I was reading over this guide, but it doesnt seem to quite answer the question.

for yes in ... This does NOT iterate over all the "yes" values, as you seem to expect...

John, no I did not expect it to work. Which is why I said something "similar" to this, and why I was asking for assistance.  I am not the most expert coder, but trying to still learn and grow. Which is why any of us are here. No reason to be rude and hateful.

This approach should work:
dict1 = { "subDict1": [ "yes", "yes", "no" ] } 
string_to_find = 'yes'
string_occurence = 0
for key, value in dict1.items():
    string_occurence += value.count(string_to_find)
print(string_occurence)

The reason that it showed 0, was that you ran through the dict itself, not the value, the lists.
Also you can not search in the dict with the variable name yes itself, you need to define it as string.
With list.count(string) you can also directly count all occurences of an item inside a list. You can find more about python data structure operations here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Assuming that you have the dict in the following form, I've given the code.
dict1 = {
        "subDict1": {"list1": [ "yes", "yes", "no" ] },
        "subDict2": {"list2": [ "no", "yes", "no" ] },
        "subDict3": {"list3": [ "yes", "yes", "yes" ] },
        "subDict4": {"list4": [ "no", "no", "no" ] }
         }

yes = 0

#iterate thru values of element of dict1
for d in dict1.values():

        #iterate thru values of previously iterated values
    for x in d.values():

        yes = yes + x.count('yes')
print(yes)  # Output : 6


Thank you, this was really helpful. Glad to know I was at least close to getting it myself! I appreciate the assistance.

There's a lot of different ways to go about this. If you'd like the simplest and easiest to understand, here's all you need to do:
#assuming dict1 = { "subDict1": {"list1": [ "yes", "yes", "no" ]} }
count = 0

for subDict in dict1.values(): #iterate through sub dictionaries of dict1
    for l in subDict.values(): #iterate through the lists in the sub dict
        for item in l: #iterate through the items in the list
            if item == "yes": count += 1 #if the item matches, add 1 to our count

print(count)

This should be pretty simple to understand if you're just getting started with Python, but I do recommend the methods shown above as it's less code that you need to write and better practice.

dict1 = { "subDict1": { "list1": [ "yes", "yes", "no" ] } }
counter = 0

for subdict in dict1.values():
    for l in subdict.values():
        counter += l.count("yes")

print(counter)

or if you want a one liner:
counter = sum(v.count("yes") for subdict in dict1.values() for v in subdict.values())
print(counter)


I'd suggest skipping the square brackets in the sum expression; no need to make a list of counts, when sum can pull from a generator expression and sum as it goes. Also, the loops in that expression need to be reversed (the leftmost is the outer loop, so as written, you're trying to loop over subdict before it even exists), so it should be sum(v.count("yes") for subdict in dict1.values() for v in subdict.values())
